How to use a variable in place of "event ID" in Eventbrite embedded checkout
I am trying to embed an eventbrite checkout within a dynamic page of my Wix site. Each page needs to have a checkout element for a different show. Very new to HTML, but, if I am understanding correctly, I need to assign the "eventID" within the createWidget method to a variable rather than a string constant. I am currently passing the eventID from my page code using the postMessage() function, but when I try to assign that data to a variable in the HTML, something seems to be going wrong. Here is what I have included in my page (Velo) code:
$w("#eventbriteSales").postMessage(964311781497);
And below is my HTML code contained within the embedded element:
`
<div id="eventbrite-widget-container-964311781497"></div>

<script src="https://www.eventbrite.com/static/widgets/eb_widgets.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  let EventbriteID = "0"
  window.onmessage = (event) => {
      if (event.data) {
         EventbriteID = event.data;
      }
  };
    var exampleCallback = function() {
        console.log('Order complete!');
    };

    window.EBWidgets.createWidget({
        // Required
        widgetType: 'checkout',
        eventId: EventbriteID,
        iframeContainerId: 'eventbrite-widget-container-964311781497',

        // Optional
        iframeContainerHeight: 425,  // Widget height in pixels. Defaults to a minimum of 425px if not provided
        onOrderComplete: exampleCallback  // Method called when an order has successfully completed
    });
</script>`


Looks like you need to move your .createWidget() call up inside your if() statement. Otherwise you could be trying to use your EventbriteID before you recieve the message that sets it's value.

Ray, thank you so much for your help! That makes sense and worked like a charm!
